# Get raw HTML on current page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to get the HTML code of the current page in Rails.

In the controller's action I need a string with that HTML code, for example:

```
<html><head></head><body><p>Hello</p></body></html>
```

The problem looks easy, but I can't find the solution.

Comment: You mean the `render_to_string` method?

Comment: Which page do you mean by current page? If you are in the `new` action, the new view has not yet been constructed, so you cannot get it. Do you mean the previous page, or a specific page? Or perhaps the page that you will render at the end of the action (in which case, @tadman's comment will work).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to render the output of an action as a string:

```
html = render_to_string(...)
```

It generally takes the same options as `render` but gives you the result you can work with instead of sending it to the client.